# AWS lambda fire event when maxReceiveCount is reached

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a Queue which will trigger a lambda. I have set maxReceiveCount to 3 so that message goes to deadleadQueue after retrying for 3 times. My requirement is to trigger another event/action from the lambda itself if it retried for 3 times. I have to call the action only after trying for the 3 times. Is there a way that lambda knows about it's retry count.

Below shows the part of my SAM template

```
  TestQueue:
    Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
    Properties:
      QueueName: TestQueue
      DelaySeconds: 0
      VisibilityTimeout: 30
      MaximumMessageSize: 28800
      MessageRetentionPeriod: 28800
      RedrivePolicy:
        deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt DLQueue.Arn
        maxReceiveCount: 3

  TestLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt QueueRole.Arn

  EventSourceMapping:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Properties:
      BatchSize: 1
      Enabled: true
      EventSourceArn: !GetAtt TestQueue.Arn
      FunctionName: !GetAtt TestLambda.Arn
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the attribute `ApproximateReceiveCount` in the SQS message to get the number of retries performed. The attribute `ApproximateReceiveCount` can be easily read within Lambda.